# WCF: Include BinarySecurityToken in logs

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security, pii

I need to include the BinarySecurityToken to a third party for an error report but WCF removes it from the logs:

```
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<!-- Removed-->
</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
```

I thought this fell under PII (Personal Identifiable Information), so I edited the machine.config & the app.config as per the instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730318.aspx

This did not work. Anyone have any ideas? If it can be done without having to edit the machine.config even better!

Cheers